# Simple browsersync config doesn't work with asterisk match pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, ejs, browser-sync

This code works fine (page is reloaded when I update index.ejs) :

```js
module.exports = {
    "port": 3001,
    "proxy": "localhost:3000",
    "files": "src/components/static/views/index.ejs"
};
```

This code doesn't work (nothing happens) :

```js
module.exports = {
    "port": 3001,
    "proxy": "localhost:3000",
    "files": "src/components/static/views/*.ejs"
};
```

Same result in a command line or in a config file.

```
"browser-sync": "^2.27.11"
```

Is it a known issue or I don't get something obvious ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the name of my root folder had a space. It was causing the problem.

I changed "My Project Name" to "MyProjectName" and it works, don't know really why.